# Wordpress Post Title Apostrophe Issue

Tags: wordpress

We are using Gravity Forms to create a custom post type - and have a special functionality on each of these post types.

All works good EXCEPT if the submitter of the custom post type enters an APOSTROPHE in the title. Then the additional details that need to show do not.....we have confirmed the apostrophe is the problem as all other pages work fine.

We have tried several sanitize options but nothing seems to work.

How can we allow the submitter to enter a post title with an apostrophe that makes Wordpress happy?

Note: It is the standard Gravity Forms post title field that we are using to feed into a custom post type from another plugin (Give WP).

Comment: I think you are looking for [a sanitizing function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data), maybe something like `esc_html()`. But without any code or example of your problem, I cannot help you.

Comment: Thanks Ron, that is what I was looking at...I am not sure what code to show ---- the gravity form feeds right into the Give WP form.....creating a custom post type. I was hoping there was a function that could be used on only GiveWP post titles somehow...

Comment: Actually it just dawned on me that I have to modify the plugin to make this work, but the link you gave is what I needed so thank you!